# Populating a list view with retrieved HTTP URLs

Tags: java, android, http, httpconnection

I am trying to create a search bar on android in  which urls are fetched from azure blob storage. I want to display the video list after the search query. But I am unable to do so.

Below is the code along with  error

```
class SearchMovies extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {

String query;
String url;
String urlOne;
String itemOne;
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Context context;
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {


   Log.i("###",s.toString());

   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   Log.i("###", "BEFORE");
                   itemOne = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); //null
                   Log.i("###AFTER", itemOne);
               }
           });

       }
   });

              /*  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Video.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://moviestarstorage.blob.core.windows.net/action-movies/ant.mp4"));
    startActivity(intent);*/
    /*Intent intent = new Intent(context,Video.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(itemOne));
    startActivity(intent);*/
    super.onPostExecute(s);
}

public SearchMovies(String passQuery, ListView passListView, Context passContext) {
    this.query = passQuery;
    this.context = passContext;
    this.listView = passListView;



}

 @Override
 protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {


    try {

        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        Log.i("###URLFromAPI", "Entered");
        url = "http://13.71.112.116/?keyword=" + query; // This is the API call
        String jsonstr = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url); //
        Log.i("###URLFromAPI", "Entered");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
        urlOne = jsonObject.getString("urls"); // urls are being fetched and logged on the screen

        String[] urlArray = urlOne.split(","); //seperating the url
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            list.add(i,urlArray[i]);
            Log.i("###FROMLOOP",list.get(i));
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //String item;
            @Override
            public void run() {

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
                Log.i("###","hello");
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i("###","hello");
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Log.i("###","BEFORE");
                       itemOne = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Log.i("###AFTER", itemOne);
                    }
                });


            }
        });*/


       /* Log.i("###",urlOne);
        if (urlOne == "") {
            Log.i("###", "URL is null");
        }
        else
            Log.i("###URLFromAPI", urlOne.toString());*/
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

Below is the error.

> com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   03-31 11:50:37.005 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7988)
>   03-31 11:50:37.005 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
>   03-31 11:50:37.005 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5426)
>   03-31 11:50:37.005 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:14959)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:14923)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:14907)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:2791)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:592)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:533)
>   03-31 11:50:37.006 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar.MainActivity$SearchMovies.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:356)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar.MainActivity$SearchMovies.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:282)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   03-31 11:50:37.007 26602-27033/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
>   03-31 11:51:36.672 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:51:36.795 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:51:36.865 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:51:36.958 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:51:36.959 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:51:36.960 26602-26602/com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   03-31 11:52:04.413 1678-8196/? W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{947dd63d0 u0 com.base.vrushali.collapsingtoolbar/.MainActivity t22054 f}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runOnUiThread` not required in `onPostExecute` it's only require when you updating `View` from `doInBackground`

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

       Log.i("###",s.toString());
               listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       Log.i("###", "BEFORE");
                       itemOne = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); //null
                       Log.i("###AFTER", itemOne);
                   }
               });


    }
```

If you are updating view in `doInBackground`

```
@Override
 protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {


    try {

        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        Log.i("###URLFromAPI", "Entered");
        url = "http://13.71.112.116/?keyword=" + query; // This is the API call
        String jsonstr = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url); //
        Log.i("###URLFromAPI", "Entered");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
        urlOne = jsonObject.getString("urls"); // urls are being fetched and logged on the screen

        String[] urlArray = urlOne.split(","); //seperating the url
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            list.add(i,urlArray[i]);
            Log.i("###FROMLOOP",list.get(i));
        }

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //String item;
            @Override
            public void run() {

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
                Log.i("###","hello");
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i("###","hello");
                           });


       /* Log.i("###",urlOne);
        if (urlOne == "") {
            Log.i("###", "URL is null");
        }
        else
            Log.i("###URLFromAPI", urlOne.toString());*/
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Tried this earlier and even now. While clicking search option, in the log we can view the urls but  it is not displaying the videos below.

Comment: @DhvaniShah can you explain in details,is it still showing same error log after applying this solution ,i think you are talking about other issue

Comment: There are no errors logs but nor the videos are being uploaded

Comment: I have updated the code,you have tried to setAdapter in background and that throw the exception,as you have keep it in try catch application is not crashed ,just check catch block is get executed with ` e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: We are near to this but now the urls are being displayed on the listview. What I want is to invoke some activity on the click of each item on the listView

Comment: @DhvaniShah so what's issue,you have added in listview right?where you want to display it?

Comment: The issue is not  of display. I want to invoke something on the click of each list item in the list view. And when I  tried to do the same my app crashed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167920/discussion-between-mjm-and-dhvani-shah).